# Asp.net mvc dyanmic checkboxlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a SQL query returning a list which i want to be displayed as check-box list.Check-box list is a part of search form which on submit is used back in sql query so need it to maintain the check-box checked state also.

Currently I am putting the list in a viewbag and rendering them , but its becoming too messy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Using a strongly typed editor will maintain the checkboxes state.

**Model**

```
public class YourViewModel
{
     public List<SelectListItem> Options
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
}
```

**View**

```
  @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Options.Count; i++)
                {

                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Options[i].Selected)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Options[i].Text)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Options[i].Value)
                    <span>@Model.Options[i].Text</span>
                }
```

**Controller Post**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(YourViewModel model)
        {
          foreach(var option in model.Options)
          {
            if(option .Selected) { // Do your logic}
          }
        }
```